# Return descending list of products by total sold from line item table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table:

```
line_item_id   order_id  product_id  qty

     1              1         144     4
     2              1         577     1
     3              1         474     1
     4              2         909     10
     5              2         474     1
```

How can I sort this table so that it returns the product_id's in a list of descending order by the total number sold (eg 909, 144, 474, 577)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select product_id, sum(qty) as qty_sum
from table
group by product_id
order by qty_sum desc
```